RS485 to CAN converter
I want to design where a RS485 Device Sensor reads inputs and the information it reads and sends is converted to CAN (Arduino UNO R4 Minima with CAN built in, or ESP32 with CAN built in)
Is this possible?
RS485 Device Sensor Inputs-->CAN Transmitter (Either built in to Arduino/ESP32 or separate)-->CAN Receiver (Either built in to Arduino/ESP32 or separate) --> Serial Monitor/Display measurement readings

RS485 is just an electrical spec, while CAN specs a complete communication system.

Counter question, why would it be impossible, what would prevent it?

When speaking of any form of data communication, it is important to be aware of the OSI model. Normally in embedded systems, it can be simplified to 3 layers: physical, data link and application.

UART is an informal data link layer specification with some default physical layer things in it. That is, it specifies voltage levels (5V or 3.3V), signal names etc but also the data frame formats and standardized baudrates.

RS-485 is a physical layer to be used with the UART data link layer.

CAN is both a physical layer and data link layer specification.

In all of the above cases you need some manner application layer or you don't have a communication link. You cannot speak of "RS-485 to CAN" etc without mentioning the application layer - you need to know this.
In some cases it is defined by the equipment you use, in other cases you have to invent it yourself. In more complex systems there are industry standard application layers like Modbus, Profibus, CANopen etc.




I want to design where a RS485 Device Sensor reads inputs and the information it reads and sends is converted to CAN
Is this possible?

Yes, no, maybe?
It is quite possible to send UART frames across a CAN physical layer transceiver, but that's quite similar to just using RS-485 transceivers so you wouldn't do that unless you have very exotic requirements.
You cannot mix UART data link layer with the CAN data link layer, that would just be utter nonsense - they are completely different.
More likely though, you'll want to take the application layer used on top of the RS-485 and translate this to something that makes sense on the application layer on top of CAN. This has to be done by software in a microcontroller.

Assuming you want to use UART protocol (or something similar)  on the RS485, then yes this is possible.

Why would other protocols be impossible? If you can receive the data regardless of format, why it can't be retransmitted over another protocol?

Others are possible if you want to bit-bang, but 99% of RS485 is UART so that's not a big limitation.

"Assuming you want to use UART protocol (or something similar) on the RS485" That's normally the case. What does this have to do with CAN and the question?

@JasenСлаваУкраїні For example SSI protocol sensors have RS-485 electrical interface but it is basically SPI instead of UART. AES3 protocol audio bitstream is also sent over RS-485. In any case, the question is poorly posed, of course converting something to something else is possible, even if it does not make sense or is useless.
